# use of getOrderTotal in Command Prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I'm trining to make a command in my Prestashop 1.7 module to create order form client cart.
When I trying to use **`$cart->getOrderTotal`** I always get a Fatal error.

```
 protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output){
    try{
        $cart = new Cart(2433);
        $total = (float)$cart->getOrderTotal(true, Cart::BOTH);
        $output->writeln('total '. $total);
    }catch (Exception $e){
        $output->writeln('error'. $e->getMessage());
        die();
    }
}
```

And the error details is:

```
Fatal error - #0 /project/classes/Product.php(3623): ToolsCore::displayError()
#1 /project/classes/Product.php(5632): ProductCore::getPriceStatic(20, false, 0, 6, NULL, false, true, 1)
#2 /project/classes/Cart.php(833): ProductCore::getProductProperties(2, Array)
#3 /project/classes/Cart.php(2144): CartCore->getProducts(false, false, NULL, true, false)
#4 /project/modules/order_install/src/Command/CheckOrderCreationCommand.php(105): CartCore->getOrderTotal(true, 4)
#5 /project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(255): order_install\Command\CheckOrderCreationCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#6 /project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(1010): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#7 /project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(86): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(order_install\Command\CheckOrderCreationCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#8 /project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(255): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(order_install\Command\CheckOrderCreationCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#9 /project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(74): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#10 /project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(148): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#11 /project/bin/console(27): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput))
#12 {main}
```

```
 protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output){
    try{
        $cart = new Cart(2433);
        $total = (float)$cart->getOrderTotal(true, Cart::BOTH);
        $output->writeln('total '. $total);
    }catch (Exception $e){
        $output->writeln('error'. $e->getMessage());
        die();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue you're encountering is due to PrestaShop core not being properly initialized in your script, which is likely causing the error you mentioned in the getPriceStatic() method.

To resolve this, you need to ensure that PrestaShop's environment is correctly set up.

Make sure you include **init.php** , something like

```
require_once('/path/to/prestashop/config/config.inc.php');
```

Also make sure Context and Employee are initialized

```
$context = Context::getContext();
$context->employee = new Employee((int)Configuration::get('PS_EMPLOYEE_ID'));
```

If you're unsure about the employee ID, you can use 1 for the super admin account in a default PrestaShop setup.